# Django FOREIGN KEY constraint failed on OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models

So I've created 2 classes of models. One has an `OneToOneField` and this class was referenced by the other using the `ForeignKey` field. It returns an error whenever I save it even in Django admin.

Model classes

```py
class First(models.Model):
  sample_field = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

# This is where I suppose to add data.
class Second(models.Model):
  another_field = models.ForeignKey(First, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='sample_related_name')
```

**Error Message**

IntegrityError at /admin/management/group/add/

FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to add models & constraints to an existing system or is the entire DB new?

Comment: Yes. I just tried to reset everything and it works.

Comment: Show code where you save model.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've just deleted the `db.sqlite3`, other migrations and migrated it again. It works fine!

Comment: Deleting the entire database and migrations to fix the issue is destruction. What if the database had data ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I appreciate your concern but it only runs in my local.